# $x \in A \notin B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Suppose I wanted to say that

$$x \in A \notin B$$.

Is there a (better) standard way to describe this? Else, I'll go for my original formulation:

$$ \ldots \text{where}\, x \in A\,\text{ but not in } B$$

Comment: Writing it in words is almost always so much clearer... To make it even better, try "where $x$ is in $A$ but not in $B$".

Comment: You could write $x \in A$, $x \notin B$. That's just a few symbols more...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you want is $x\in A\setminus B$: the set $A\setminus B$ is by definition the set of things that are in $A$ but not in $B$. (An older notation is $A-B$; I don’t recommend it.)

The expression $x\in A\notin B$ says something entirely different: it says that $x$ is an element of $A$, and $A$ is not an element of $B$.

Answer (score 9):

Your statement can be written with the set-minus character: $\setminus$

(For typesetting in LaTeX, for example, on math.se: use `\setminus`):

$$x \in A\setminus B,$$ which is defined to be exactly:

$$x \in A \land x \notin B$$

While you can chain together set inclusion $\subset$, e.g. $x \in A \subset B \subset C$ from which it follows that  $x \in A \land x\in B \land x\in C$, that's not appropriate for set membership:
$$x \in A \notin B \not\equiv x \in A \land x \notin B.$$

Comment: So, you suggested \setminus rather than -? +)

Answer (score 2):

Next formula describes your relation

$A \ni x \notin B$

Comment: Some might argue that you are prefacing a statement about A, with asserting "A such that x is not in B" which might be confusing. There was just yesterday a "debate" about the notation $\ni$ and its signification: "such that..." vs. reversed set-inclusion (the correlate of $\supset$), etc. Anyway, +1 for the creativity!

Comment: Just look at the LaTeX notation to clarify the meaning of $\ni$.

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)

Comment: @Sergei...I agree...just mentioning that some want if for "such that"...

Comment: $\ni$ does not appear to be in that table. Even if it were, it is still a confusing notation since many people use $\ni$ and/or $\backepsilon$ to mean "such that". A more common notation would be $x\in A\setminus B$ or $x\in A-B$

Comment: @robjohn Wiki was about "such that". It may be expressed as ":" or "|". If some people use $\ni$ as "such that" they do it wrong. There is nothing in use two relations in one expression instead of two expressions. Like $1<x<2$. But yes, $x \in A \backslash B$ is more clear to understand.

Comment: Just because that page does not list $\ni$ for "such that", does not mean it is not used as such. However, it is definitely uncommon to see a symbol and its reverse in an inequality or inclusion. For example, I don't think I have ever seen $x\gt y\lt z$.

Comment: Potentially, $\ni$ for reverse inclusion could be useful. For instance, if you want to sum over all sets $A$ containing $x$, you could write $\sum_{A \ni x} f(A)$. But I have to agree that $A \ni x \notin B$ is ugly...